# Syntax Error when Inner Joining two tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to join tables *events* and *venues*, however I ran into an issue whilst inner joining. This is how I did it:

```
$query =    "SELECT e.*, v.* FROM events e WHERE start_datetime >= '$DATE_START_SELECTED' AND end_datetime < '$DATE_END_SELECTED'".
           "INNER JOIN venues v ON e.VENUE_LOCATION = v.VENUE_ID";
```

And for some reason I have an error like this:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INNER JOIN venues v ON e.VENUE_LOCATION = v.VENUE_ID' at line 1

Any idea why? Thanks!

---

**Edit:**

I updated the code to look like this:

```
$query =    "SELECT e.*, v.* FROM events e ".
        "INNER JOIN venues v ON e.VENUE_LOCATION = v.VENUE_ID".
        "WHERE start_datetime >= '$DATE_START_SELECTED' AND end_datetime < '$DATE_END_SELECTED'";
```

Only to get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'start_datetime >= '2012-03-15 06:00:00' AND end_datetime <
>   '2012-03-16 05:59:00'' at line 1

Comment: re: your update - put a space after `v.VENUE_ID"` and before the `WHERE`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `INNER JOIN` needs to come before the `WHERE` clause.

E.g.,

```
select e.*, v.*
from events e
inner join venues v on e.VENUE_LOCATION = v.VENUE_ID
where start_datetime >= '$DATE_START_SELECTED' 
    and end_datetime < '$DATE_END_SELECTED'
```

Comment: Aaha... Will know from now on. Thank you RedFilter :)!

Answer (score 1):

Joins always come after the `from` and before the `where`. So, your query will read more like the below:

```
SELECT e.*, v.* 
FROM events e 
    INNER JOIN venues v ON e.VENUE_LOCATION = v.VENUE_ID
WHERE start_datetime >= '$DATE_START_SELECTED' 
    AND end_datetime < '$DATE_END_SELECTED'
```

Answer (score 1):

Write the where clause at the end (and I'd also extend the shorthand notations like "FROM events e to FROM events AS e:

```
SELECT e.*, v.* FROM events AS e 
INNER JOIN venues AS v ON e.VENUE_LOCATION = v.VENUE_ID
WHERE e.start_datetime >= yourVar AND e.end_datetime < yourOtherVar;
```

Comment: Forgot to mention I've also qualified start_datetime and end_datetime to e.start_datetime and e.end_datetime, which I presume to be in the events table. This avoids confusion should you join tables with identically named fields.